# Count and flatten in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, flatten, cloudera-cdh

Hi I have a data like this :

{"user_id": "kim95", "type": "Book", "title": "Modern Database Systems: The Object Model, Interoperability, and Beyond.", "year": "1995", "publisher": "ACM Press and Addison-Wesley", "authors": [{"name":"null"}], "source": "DBLP"}

{"user_id": "marshallo79", "type": "Book", "title": "Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Application.", "year": "1979", "publisher": "Academic Press", "authors": [{"name":"Albert W. Marshall"},{"name":"Ingram Olkin"}], "source": "DBLP"}

{"user_id": "knuth86a", "type": "Book", "title": "TeX: The Program", "year": "1986", "publisher": "Addison-Wesley", "authors": [{"name":"Donald E. Knuth"}], "source": "DBLP"}
...

And I would like to get the publisher,title and then applied a count on the group but I got error ' a column needs to be...' with this script :

```
books = load 'data/book-seded-workings-reduced.json'
    using JsonLoader('user_id:chararray,type:chararray,title:chararray,year:chararray,publisher:chararray,authors:{(name:chararray)},source:chararray');

doc = group books by publisher;
res = foreach doc generate group,books.title,count(books.publisher);
DUMP res;
```

On a second query I would like to have a structure like this :(name,year),title

So I tried this one :

```
books = load 'data/book-seded-workings-reduced.json'
    using JsonLoader('user_id:chararray,type:chararray,title:chararray,year:chararray,publisher:chararray,authors:{(name:chararray)},source:chararray');


flat =group books by (generate FLATTEN((authors.name),year);
tab = foreach flat generate group, books.title;
DUMP tab;
```

But it also doesn't work...

Any idea please?

Comment: Can you be more clear on what is the output you are expecting

Comment: For the first one I woukd like an output like:      publisher, title and the number of times the same publisher is on my file loaded

Comment: For the secpnd I want a list of the each name of authirs with the year in a group...and then the title of the books

Comment: So something like (name, year) in group and generate the title linked with that group for each tuples: (name, year), title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the error you are getting on trying out the first query?
COUNT being inbuilt function has to be in all caps, you cannot invoke COUNT(group), group is internal identifier generated by Pig.

I get following result on running your first query -

(Academic Press,{(Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Application.)},1)
(Addison-Wesley,{(TeX: The Program)},1)
(ACM Press and Addison-Wesley,{(Modern Database Systems: The Object Model, Interoperability, and Beyond.)},1)

The expected format of (name,year), title can also be achieved this way -

```
flat = foreach books generate FLATTEN(authors.name) as authorName, year, title;
tab = group flat by (authorName, year);
finaltab = foreach tab generate group, flat.title;
```

Comment: Sorry I can't tell you right now my error I don't have my laptop in front of my eyes....for the first script did you used my script??? It's strange that it works for you. ..Can you retry the same script but by adding in the file loaded one or more tuples with the same name of the publisher and whatever you want for others fields to bu sure that's okay? I'll post my error later...thank you very much for the second script

Comment: I tested it again with COUNT caps on and it works....what did you mean by the fact I cannot invoke group in COUNT? because the script worked... thanks for the second

Answer (score 1):

Only problem in your first code i could see is "COUNT"  instead of count (CAPS on)

if you use without caps count then you will get a error

Could not resolve count using imports: